# jQuery sortable can't drag from a handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, drag, handle

Why can't I drag a sortable item if it's also a handle?

Is there any workaround?

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/hQsjD/8/

```
<script>
    var container = $(".con");
    container.sortable({
        handle: '.handle'
    });
</script>
    <div class="con">
    <div class="handle">handle</div>
    <div class="handle">handle</div>
    <div class="handle">handle</div>
    <div class="handle">handle</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kinda defeats the purpose. A handle is a certain area inside the draggable element that works like a ... wait for it ....
handle.

Using the entire element as a handle makes no sense, as you could do that by just calling sortable without a handle :

```
$(".con").sortable();
```

and the entire element would be the handle by default.

If you really want a handle, you need to define that handle as a certain area inside the element, like so:

```
<div class="con">
    <div><span class="handle">X</span>handle</div>
    <div><span class="handle">X</span>handle</div>
    <div><span class="handle">X</span>handle</div>
    <div><span class="handle">X</span>handle</div>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hQsjD/9/)